# Using Jquery/Javascript to access JSON embedded in XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, json

I have a jquery function which communicates with an ASP.NET web service which looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                         $.support.cors = true;
             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "http://www.webservice.com/blahblah.asmx/blahb123",
                 data: "tnWsGuid=TEST1",
                 dataType: "text",
                 success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
                     xmlString = data;
                     alert(xmlString);
                 },
                 error: function (request, status, error) {
                     alert(status);
                 }

                });
        });
```

Alert display's this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<string xmlns = "http://Walkthrough/XmlWebServices/">
{"approverName":"","emailAddress":"","companyName":"ABC","address":{"streetAddress1":"12 BlahBlah","streetAddress2":"","state":"ON","zipCode":"","country":"SO","phoneNumber":""},"tabledata:"[{"vendorPart":"AAAAA","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"28"},{"vendorPart":"BBBBBBB","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"3"},{"vendorPart":"CCCCCC","partDescription":"N/A","price":"0.00","quantity":"25"}]}
</string>
```

My dataType is now text. I know how to parse JSON however, now what I need to do is somehow access the JSON embedded in the XML envelope and turn it into a JSON object so I can use JQuery to parse it.

Here is what I have tried in the $.ajax function:

```
success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
                     xmlString = data;
                     var jsondata = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlString.substr(xmlString.indexOf('{')));
                     alert(jsondata);
                 }
```

But was returned with an error of Invalid character which in the IE debugger [look's like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNa3T.png)

Any idea how I can access the data inside the xml envelope and turn it into a JSON object so I can parse it as JSON? I do not have the ability to change the web service so this must all be done within the web page.

Comment: Note that `$.support.cors = true` doesn't actually do anything unless the current browser supports CORS and jQuery incorrectly detects that it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason you have JSON inside XML and not just return the JSON directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
    var xml = $($.parseXML(data)), // Parse the XML String to a Document, and Wrap jQuery
        json = xml.find("string").text(), // Get the text of the XML
        jsonObj = $.parseJSON(json); // Parse the JSON String
}
```

Or short notation

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON($($.parseXML(data)).find("string").text());
```

Live Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59rQA/

Comment: This worked for me, tested it out and did jsonObj.companyName within the alert and it showed the right stuff! Marking this as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your substring is adding the closing tag for  to the JSON data.
    How about:

```
xmlString = $.parseXML(xmlString);
var jsondata = $.parseJSON($(xmlString).children('string').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

As your call is returning xml, you could use `dataType:"xml"` instead of "text".

You can then process the xml response:

```
var jsonData=$.parseJSON(data.find("string").text());
```

Comment: You forgot data needs to be $(data). Other than that, I prefer this answer.